# symfony2 entity relationship

Tags: symfony

I try to make a social network with symfony2. I am not sure of how to modelize a user and his friends in the User entity.
I mean a friend is also a user so I have a User entity linked to another User entity.

How in the annotation of the User entity can I express that kind of relationship?
For the moment I have something like :
the User entity :

```
...
/**
 * @ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity="User")
 *
 */
private $friends;
...
```

with $friends as an arraycollection. Is it correct?

Comment: Yes, that is correct.

Answer (score 0):

That is a self-referencing `ManyToMany` relationship. It's actually the example used in the [documentation](http://doctrine-orm.readthedocs.org/en/latest/reference/association-mapping.html#many-to-many-self-referencing).

Basically, you would so something like this:

```
<?php
/** @Entity **/
class User
{
    // ...

    /**
     * @ManyToMany(targetEntity="User", mappedBy="myFriends")
     **/
    private $friendsWithMe;

    /**
     * @ManyToMany(targetEntity="User", inversedBy="friendsWithMe")
     * @JoinTable(name="friends",
     *      joinColumns={@JoinColumn(name="user_id", referencedColumnName="id")},
     *      inverseJoinColumns={@JoinColumn(name="friend_user_id", referencedColumnName="id")}
     *      )
     **/
    private $myFriends;

    public function __construct() {
        $this->friendsWithMe = new \Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection();
        $this->myFriends = new \Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection();
    }

    // ...
}
```

Note that it's set as a bidirectional relation. That is, you can get the list of friends *and* the list of people that are friends with a `User`.

Comment: Thank you for your responses. I'm going to study the documentation. For the moment my solution seems to work.